# Why does dir *.txt return *.txtf also?

Tags: batch-file, wildcard, dir

No doubt this has been answered already :/  I'm not certain how to word this.  **I just want the file one.txt to return by what I thought would be dir *.txt**

Here are some examples to show that it doesn't behave like I had thought.

dir *.txt

```
one.txt
one.txtf
```

dir *txt

```
one.txt
one.txtf
```

dir *txtf

```
one.txtf
```

dir *tx?

```
one.txt
one.txtf
```

dir *.???

```
one.txt
one.txtf
```

dir one.???

```
one.txt
```

dir *"."???

```
one.txt
one.txtf
```

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/63777/how-can-i-get-the-dir-and-copy-commands-to-operate-on-xyz-but-not-xyz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### EDITED

In short - by definition the DIR command works as you're implying so it's one of those "by design" things.

From Microsoft on the [DIR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755121%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command directly.  This explanation is a bit more winded than the below from the .NET framework.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) on the .NET Framework Implementation

> When using the asterisk wildcard character in a searchPattern, such as "*.txt", the matching behavior when the extension is exactly three characters long is different than when the extension is more or less than three characters long. A searchPattern with a file extension of exactly three characters returns files having an extension of three or more characters, where the first three characters match the file extension specified in the searchPattern. A searchPattern with a file extension of one, two, or more than three characters returns only files having extensions of exactly that length that match the file extension specified in the searchPattern. When using the question mark wildcard character, this method returns only files that match the specified file extension. For example, given two files, "file1.txt" and "file1.txtother", in a directory, a search pattern of "file?.txt" returns just the first file, while a search pattern of "file*.txt" returns both files.

Comment: +1, great reference, terrible shocking design on MicroSoft's part.

Comment: While your link certainly appears relevant, it's not obvious that a .NET Framework reference would necessarily document the behavior of `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @jjlin Right you are, though they are effectively interchangable because Microsoft needed to implement it consistently with their OS, I have updated the answer with a more direct link to the DIR command.  I have no included a quote however because the explanation is more complex and winded.