# batch wildcards extending extension

Tags: batch-file, wildcard

So from [Why does dir *.txt return *.txtf also?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424577/why-does-dir-txt-return-txtf-also) tells me that the reason my

```
del /S moc_*.cxx call is also deleting moc_foo.cxx_parameters
```

If I do not know the length of foo, is there any way in windows to delete only the .cxx files?

EDIT
I have found an "equivalent" call is

```
forfiles /S /m *.cxx /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

And to do it quietly if the file is not found

```
forfiles /S /m *.cxx /c "cmd /c del @file" 2> nul
```

What a terrible design!

Comment: The del command run as espected with your filenames, Also I read your other post but the dir command works as expected too, it matchs "file.txt" but not "file.txtf". You are using Windows XP or earlier? the * patterns works as expected on win7

Comment: @ElektroHacker - The answer in the linked question does a poor job explaining a very real problem. A file mask with wildcards may match either the full, long name, or the short 8.3 name.

Comment: @ElektroHacker It doe NOT function "as expected" on win7, it functions the same...basically a wildcard doesn't really mean "match the other characters with as many character where the wild card is". It means "I want to find this file" and "Windows can guess the file-name for me" which is, as I said, A TERRIBLE DESIGN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for %i in (moc_*.cxx) do if /i "%~xi"==".cxx" ECHO del "%i"

should select only .cxx files for deletion. Remove the `echo` keyword to execute the deletion after verification. Change `%` to `%%` throughout to use `within` a batch file.

Comment: You might like to add /i in `if /i "%~xi"==".cxx"` in your post.