# Odd behavior with the DEL command

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Was writing a short script to search out all files with a certain extension, rename them and delete them... but I noticed some odd behavior in the delete script.

Let's say I have four files: **file.lo**, **file.log**, **file.logs**, & **file.logarithm**

If I use the command `del /s /q /f *.lo` then only **file.lo** is deleted. If I use the command `del /s /q /f *.logs` then only **file.logs** is deleted.

But if I use the command `del /s /q /f *.log` then **.log, .logs, and .logarithm** are deleted. The only file that remains is file.lo

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Do you have a typo in your question?  You've shown `del /s /q /f *.logs` twice in the question but listed different results.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11424588/5022761), using an extension of exactly 3 characters in a search pattern causes the search to also return matching files with longer extensions, and otherwise allways finds exactly the right files. You should apparently use `"file?.log"`, `"file.log."` as Stephan suggests, or one of [these suggestions](https://superuser.com/a/63839/553079)

Answer (score 2):

Explanation: `file.logarithm` matches the 8.3 short name `file.log`

Workaround: `del file.log.`